# List with in a List of System::Collections::Generic::List<T> type is possible?

Tags: c#, c++

In c#:

```
public static List<List<int>> StopCapture()
{
  List<List<int>> Data = new List<List<int>>();
 //data.add() some data is added is here
 return Data;
```

}

In c++:
am trying to collect like this

```
List<List<int>^>^ captureCommandStrings = gcnew List<List<int>>();  
captureCommandStrings = StopCapture();
```

Error :
 generic type argument for 'T' cannot be 'System::Collections::Generic::List', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the 'hat' at the end of your instantiation:

```
List<List<int>^> ^Data = gcnew List<List<int>^>();
```

i.e., if you declare 'Data' as a managed pointer to a List of managed pointers to a List of int, then your instantiation also has to be creating a List of managed pointers to a List of int (instead of a List of List of int).